# Override CSS class using JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, overriding, reveal.js

I am using Reveal JS. This is the CSS that I want to override:

```
.reveal section img {...
```

Using one of the methods below (or something better), how can I use JS to override that?

```
document.getElementById(image1).classList.add("red"); // I tried creating a CSS class called "red" but it doesn't overide the original
document.getElementById(image1).style.boxShadow = "red"; // this doesn't overide the original theme CSS
```

Comment: show the actual styles you want to override - if it is box shadow - isn't it expecting some measurements for the shadow too, instead of just a colour?  eg: `5px 2px 2px red`.  Also if your class didn't work, I think you need to have a read up on css specificity and order

Comment: `box-shadow: red` is not valid CSS

Comment: Sorry for the dumb question. I guess that solves it. I thought I could just change the color since a box shadow already existed for it.

Comment: if `image1` is the actual ID and not a variable name, you'll need quotes around it: `document.getElementById("image1")`.

Comment: it is a variable name but thanks for the comment anyway

Answer (score 0):

First, use chrome dev tools to make sure that the class is actually being added to the element.

If it is being added but the styles are not being applied, your problems may be stemming from [css specificity rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Instead of  defining your class like this:

```
.red {
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 2px red;
}
```

Try this:

```
.reveal section img.red {
  box-shadow: 5px 2px 2px red;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work but for some reason this does: .reveal section img.red {